# Represent time-series data in much compact form

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

I have time series data of one month plotted day-wise as
[image]

Notice **every day follows a different pattern**. Now, I want to show this "diversity in pattern" of each day in much compact form in a research paper. What are the different ways/options of representing this in compact form using R.

Comment: Are you thinking visual representation, or mathematical? If it's the former, look at [sparklines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline). If it's the latter, look at PCA; the PCA coefficients will give you a succinct summary.

Comment: Thanks @Emre for pointing to sparklines,  but sparklines still take enough space on paper,i.e, thirty rows (for each day). I want something more compact.

Comment: How about 2D PCA? Each time series will be represented as a point on one chart.

Comment: Sparklines is a good idea, maybe just comma-seperated next to each other (depending on what you wanna show) - just like flowing text, Or plot several lines in one chart - maybe 4 to 5 lines per 7 charts if you aggregate by weekday. But I guess you already tried that...

Comment: Difficult to say but if you might have expected periodicity then Panel of 4 (and 1 of 3), with 7 colours for 7 days would be compact and show/not show the relation? You would also want to do something like ARIMA plot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simulate some data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(ggthemes)

days <- seq(as.Date("2015-08-01"), as.Date("2015-08-31"), by="1 day")
hours <- sprintf("%02d", 0:23)

map_df(days, function(x) {
  map_df(hours, function(y) {
    data.frame(day=x, hour=y, val=sample(2500, 1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })
}) -> df
```

Check it:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=hour, y=val, group=day)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~day) +
  theme_tufte(base_family="Helvetica") +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

[image]

Since you're only trying to convey the scope of the variation, perhaps use a boxplot of the values of hours across days?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=hour, y=val)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="#2b2b2b", alpha=0.25, width=0.75, size=0.25) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_tufte(base_family="Helvetica") +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

[image]

That can be tweaked to fit into most publication graphics slots and the boxplot shows just how varied each day's readings are.

You could also use `boxplot.stats` to get the summary data and plot it on a line chart:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bps <- function(x) {
  cnf <- boxplot.stats(x)$conf
  data.frame(as.list(set_names(cnf, c("lwr", "upr"))), mean=mean(x))
}

group_by(df, hour) %>% 
  do(bps(.$val)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=hour, y=mean, ymin=lwr, ymax=upr, group=1)) +
  geom_ribbon(fill="#2b2b2b", alpha=0.25) +
  geom_line(size=0.25) +
  theme_tufte(base_family="Helvetica") +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two alternative way are a *density plot* for each hour and *level plot* of hour and factorized value.

I'm showing ganarated data with two different unified distribution (for day and night hours)

**Densityplot**

```
library(lattice)
xy <- densityplot(~ value,  groups = hour ,   
plot.points=FALSE, 
data =  df,   
scales=list(x=list(rot=90, cex= .9 ),y=list(cex=.9)),par.strip.text=list(cex=.8),   
ylab="density", xlab="value", main=paste(  "DensityPlot"  ) )
print (xy)
```

[image]

**Levelplot**

```
library(RColorBrewer)
xy <- levelplot(cnt ~    hour + value,   
 col.regions=colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))(16) ,
data =  df,   
scales=list(x=list(rot=90, cex= .9 ),y=list(cex=.9)),par.strip.text=list(cex=.8),   
ylab="value", xlab="hour", main=paste( "LevelPlot"  ) )
print (xy)
```

[image]